# SQL Command retrieve List nested inside column

Tags: sql-server, select, nested

Consider this table:

```
Employees   Segment     Function    
John        Retail      Sales
Peter       Retail      Sales
Lucas       Retail      Sales
Steve       Retail      Sales
Maria       Retail      Sales
```

I want a list resulting, like this: (alias for the first column)

```
'Area'  'Employees'
Retail  John,Lucas,Maria
Sales   John,Lucas,Maria
```

To assemble the query I have only the list of Employees. So the condition should be something, like:

```
WHERE Employees IN('John','Maria','Lucas').
```

I only have access to query the DB.

I can mount the Employees list in a row, like this:

```
SELECT 
Employees = Stuff(
  (SELECT N', ' + Employees FROM table A WHERE Employees
        IN('John','Maria','Lucas') FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
  .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'');
```

And I can create the 'Area' by merging Segment and Function like this:

```
SELECT Segment 'Area' FROM table
WHERE Employees IN('John','Maria','Lucas')
UNION SELECT Function 'Area' FROM table
WHERE Employees IN('John','Maria','Lucas')
```

I'd like to just merge those two selects using something as UNION, like this:

```
SELECT 
    Employees = Stuff(
      (SELECT N', ' + Employees FROM table A WHERE Employees
            IN('John','Maria','Lucas') FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
      .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'')
    UNION
    SELECT Segment 'Area' FROM table
    WHERE Employees IN('John','Maria','Lucas')
    UNION SELECT Function 'Area' FROM table
    WHERE Employees IN('John','Maria','Lucas')
```

The result came out, like:

```
'Employees'
John,Maria,Lucas
Retail
Sales
```

Maybe I'm missing some detail on the UNION syntax, or it's not so simple as I expected.

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? You tagged sql server and mysql but then you mention PL/SQL (Oracle) in your question.

Comment: Also, you need to define "didn't work out". What does that mean?

Comment: I think you are probably looking for GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: Sean, it's MS Sql-server, actually. Fixing the tags.

Comment: @SeanLange edited with the return from DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use your UNION, you just have to do the STUFF() twice.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Segment AS 'Area'
                , Stuff((SELECT N', ' + Employees 
                        FROM table A 
                        WHERE Employees IN('John','Maria','Lucas') 
                        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'') FROM table
WHERE Employees IN ('John','Maria','Lucas')
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Func AS 'Area'
            , Stuff((SELECT N', ' + Employees 
                    FROM table A 
                    WHERE Employees IN('John','Maria','Lucas') 
                    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'') FROM table
WHERE Employees IN ('John','Maria','Lucas')
```

Comment: Just edited your query to add the alias for the second row:
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'') as 'Employees';

It was returning as 'no name column'

Answer (score 1):

Hoping, this will fulfill your requirement.

Tried it on sqlfiddle, works fine.

```
SELECT  a.Fun Area, 
        SUBSTRING(d.Employees,1, LEN(d.Employees) - 1) Employees
FROM( SELECT DISTINCT Fun FROM test_so) a
        CROSS APPLY
        (SELECT [Employees] + ', ' FROM test_so AS B WHERE A.Fun = B.Fun FOR XML PATH('')
        ) D (Employees)     
UNION
SELECT  a.Segment Area, SUBSTRING(d.Employees,1, LEN(d.Employees) - 1) Employees
FROM( SELECT DISTINCT Segment FROM test_so) a
        CROSS APPLY
        ( SELECT [Employees] + ', ' FROM test_so AS B WHERE A.Segment = B.Segment FOR XML PATH('')
        ) D (Employees)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to copy your fiddle and couldn't make it work. The syntax is not clear to me, but it seems very elegant. Could you elaborate a bit more? Or provide the SQLFiddle link?